# Is it possible to create a multimachine vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-provision

Right now I have a multi-machine vagrant setup, that I provision and run locally. Provisioning takes a lot of time and I would like to avoid it by provisioning it once and then distributing it as a vagrant box.

I know one can make a box out of one vagrant machine, is it possible to do the same for 3? I would like the end-user just to run `vagrant init` and to have a setup of 3 provisioned machines.

If not, could you please point me to the best possible solution for this?

*Edit.* The three machines contain different apps that interact with each other:
1) App server
2) App client
3) Pytest driver

As @MattSchuchard pointed out in the comments, I could provision 3 identical boxes with full set of apps and launch only one of them (although the 2 are available).
Distributing several vagrant boxes in a set appears to be impossible.

Comment: You would need to make a base box and then provision the three machines uniquely from the same box. More information is needed to elaborate on this.

Comment: you may need to change the vagrant file content. Is this what you are looking for?